# Reading data from Excel sheet 2007 in JAVA

Tags: java, excel, excel-2007, xlsx

I am having a problem when trying to read an Excel 2007 spreadsheet (.xlsx).  I am trying to implement the method in JAVA by using the [POI library](http://poi.apache.org/), but I get this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlException

and this is my method:

```
public void No_rows() throws IOException  {
    File inputWorkbook = new File(inputFile);
    FileInputStream w = new FileInputStream(inputWorkbook);
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(w);
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    Iterator rows = sheet.rowIterator();
    int number=sheet.getLastRowNum();
    this.num_rows = number;
    w.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is to create and read an *.xlsx file. If you get that error, include the `jaxp--api-1.4.jar`.

```
public class Readxlsx {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try 
        {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("D:\\prac\\sample1.xlsx"));
            XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();

            for(int m=0;m<3;m++){
                if(m==0)
                {
                    XSSFSheet  sh = wb.createSheet("Sachin"); 
                    System.out.println(" Sheet NO:"+m);

                    for (int k = 0; k < 30; k++) {
                        XSSFRow row = sh.createRow((short)k);
                        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
                            XSSFCell cell = row.createCell((short)i);
                            cell.setCellValue(wb.getSheetName(m)+i);
                        }
                    }

                }
                else if(m==1){
                    XSSFSheet sh1 = wb.createSheet("Dravid");  
                    System.out.println(" Sheet NO:"+m);

                    for (int k = 0; k < 30; k++) {
                        XSSFRow row = sh1.createRow((short)k);
                        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
                            XSSFCell cell = row.createCell((short)i);
                            cell.setCellValue(wb.getSheetName(m)+i);
                        }
                    }

                }
                else 
                {

                    XSSFSheet sh2 = wb.createSheet("Dhoni");  
                    System.out.println(" Sheet NO:"+m);

                    for (int k = 0; k < 30; k++) {
                        XSSFRow row = sh2.createRow((short)k);
                        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
                            XSSFCell cell = row.createCell((short)i);
                            cell.setCellValue(wb.getSheetName(m)+i);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            wb.write(fos);
            fos.close();

            fis= new FileInputStream(new File("D:\\prac\\sample1.xlsx"));
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            java.util.Iterator<org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row> rows =  sheet.rowIterator();
            int number=sheet.getLastRowNum();
            System.out.println(" number of rows"+ number);

            while (rows.hasNext())
            {
                XSSFRow row = ((XSSFRow) rows.next());
                int r=row.getRowNum();
                System.out.println(" Row NO:"+r);
                java.util.Iterator<org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell> cells = row.cellIterator();

                while(cells.hasNext()) {
                    XSSFCell cell = (XSSFCell) cells.next();
                    String Value=cell.getStringCellValue();
                    System.out.println(Value);
                }
           }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Michael-O in the comments, XML Beans are missing from the classpath. The XMLBeans library can be found at http://xmlbeans.apache.org/ .

Answer (score 0):

[xml bean library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XhzN.png)

You have to include xmlbeans library in your build path. It is usually in your ooxml-lib in your poi-apache library.